# Eclipse cannot write file

Tags: eclipse, file-permissions

Hi I'm developing a website using php

For security all file and folder has "www-data:developer" owner and a permission of "570 (r-xrwx---)"

My login user is also in "developer" group

Now I'm able to edit and read the file using vim
But when using Eclipse it always read-only, why ?

I open eclipse using the same login user. Is it possible when open eclipse it doesn't use my login user ? I install just by extracting the compress file downloaded from eclipse

Environment :
Linux Mint 17.1 ( base on Ubuntu 14.04 )

Comment: Sure you're eclipse workspace root folder is :developer - 570 ? You can check your username while running eclipse on "help" -> "About" -> "instalation details" -> "configuration" -> "user.name=???"

Comment: user.name is the same as my login user. my workspace is PHP/<project directory>, the PHP folder is using 755 permission but all the project directory is 570

Comment: This is how I set folder permission

usermod -a -G developer <my login user>,
chown -R www-data <project folder>,
chgrp -R developer <project folder>,
chmod -R 570 <project folder>

Comment: I set to 577 also not working, maybe java permission ?

Comment: It seems Eclipse doesn't check the file group permission

owner : group owner |user : group : other
www-data : developer | r-x : rwx : --- > Eclipse cannot write
www-data : developer | rwx : rwx : --- > Eclipse cannot write
eclipseuser : www-data | rwx : r-x : --- > Eclipse can write

Note : eclipseuser is belong to the developer group

so It is possible to make eclipse check if he belong to the group ?

Comment: Sorry, actually i don't have a unix-system here, so i can't test. If i remember right, you can see your current groups with "group" or "groups". Are you sure, you're trying to write in this directory? Have you tried "chmod -R 777", is it working then?